# Почему не отображаются svg иконки в IE11?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, svg, кроссбраузерность

Вставляю svg в html с помощью use, указывая пространство имён svg:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100" height="35" role="img" class="logo__mobile">
  <use xlink:href="img/svgcombine-file.svg#logo-mobile"></use>
</svg>
```

в начале html документа указываю

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Но в IE11 всё равно отображаются только svg, которые непосредственно находятся в размётке, а те, что вставлены с помощью "use" отображаются только в Chrome и Mozilla.
Кто-то сталкивался с подобным?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[IE11 не поддерживает `<use>`](https://css-tricks.com/svg-use-external-source/) (как и 10, и 9), но есть [полифилл](https://github.com/Keyamoon/svgxuse).

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!